# Extracting domain and path from website

Tags: c#, path, extract

I want to extract the domain and path from a list of websites. For example, if the website is http://www.domain.com/path1/page1.html I would like to get http://www.domain.com/path1/ and if the website is http://www.domain2.com/path2/page2/ I would like to get http://www.domain2.com/path2/.

I tried downloading the page and retrieve all anchors but I could only get the relative path of the file (/page1.html and /page2/ in this case). Is there a way for me to achieve what I want?

Comment: What programming language are you using to parse the URLs?!

Comment: I would guess C#, as all of the OPs other questions are for C#.

Answer (score 0):

path2 is not something that is always present in all urls. so you will not get a ready made method to parse that.
I would suggest write a function for that
Very roughly, to give you an idea:

```
var index = url.IndexOf(".com/");
var substringAfterFirstSlash = url.SubString(index, url.Length + 1 - index)
var indexOfSecondSlash = substringAfterFirstSlash.IndexOf("/") + index;
var yourPath = url.SubString(0, indexOfSecondSlash+1 );
```